# 2D Array to take float inputs from user and calculate sum of columns

Tags: java, sum, decimal, multiple-columns

I'm really new to Java and have been given a task to create a two dimensional array that takes input from the user. The problem I am having is that it needs to take in some decimal numbers as well as whole numbers then calculate the sum of each column and my program is returning an error once a decimal number is input. I have tried changing all instances of "int" to "float" but still the same error pops up. I also then need to print out the totals of each column.

My code so far is:

```
    package sumElements;
    import java.util.Scanner;



    public class sumElements{



    public static void main(String args[]){
    int row, col, i, j;
    int arr[][] = new int[3][4];
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    // enter row and column for array.
    row = 3;
    col = 4;

    // enter array elements.
    System.out.println("Enter " +(row*col)+ " array elements row by row (4 per row) : ");
    for(i=0; i<row; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<col; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
        }
    }

    // the 2D array is here.
    System.out.print("The Array is :\n");
    for(i=0; i<row; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<col; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[i][j]+ "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }



   }

}
```

Changed code:

```
package sumElements;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class sumElements{



public static void main(String args[]){
    float row, col, i, j;
    float arr[][] = new float[3][4];
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    // enter row and column for array.
    row = 3;
    col = 4;

    // enter array elements.
    System.out.println("Enter " +(row*col)+ " array elements row by row (4 per row) : ");
    for(i=0; i<row; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<col; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = scan.nextFloat();
        }
    }

    // the 2D array is here.
    System.out.print("The Array is :\n");
    for(i=0; i<row; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<col; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[i][j]+ "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }



}
```

}

Comment: "some error'' pop ups, could you be more specific? Also, read up on naming conventions (for instance about class names), it 'll make your code easier to read

Comment: What error are you getting? This code clearly accepts ints only.

Comment: Sorry i should have mentioned that. After changing all the instances of int to float I get an error on line 25:           arr[i] [j] = scan.nextFloat();

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: It says it cannot convert "int" to "float" ... I have changed all "ints" to "float". Is there a specific way of doing this?

Comment: Post the whole code with everything changed.

Comment: I don't think this is your bug, but row, col, I, and jay should still be int.

Answer (score 0):

```
package sumElements;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class sumElements{



public static void main(String args[]){
    int row, col, i, j;
    float arr[][] = new float[3][4];
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    // enter row and column for array.
    row = 3;
    col = 4;

    // enter array elements.
    System.out.println("Enter " +(row*col)+ " array elements row by row (4 per row) : ");
    for(i=0; i<row; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<col; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = scan.nextFloat();
        }
    }

    // the 2D array is here.
    System.out.print("The Array is :\n");
    for(i=0; i<row; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<col; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[i][j]+ "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }



}
```

Indices must be int since elements of the array float

Comment: Thanks for the advice Jimmy but once I enter a decimal number. I get an error... Exception in thread "main"

Comment: Its returning the array as floats but not actually taking them in. Example: 5.0  2.0  3.0. 1.0  but as soon as I input a decimal number (2.4) it crashes